# currval Function in PostgreSQL complaining that "column does not exist"

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use PostgreSQL's `currval` function to return the last inserted row id of a table called `Concept`.  `Concept` has a serial primary key called `cid` and there was an automatically generated Sequence called `Concept_cid_seq`.

I try the following statement and get an error:

```
SELECT currval("Concept_cid_seq");
ERROR:  column "Concept_cid_seq" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT currval("Concept_cid_seq");
                       ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "Concept_cid_seq" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 16
```

But when I run the query :

```
SELECT * from "Concept_cid_seq";
```

I get a table with one row (as I'd expect) showing columns like last_value, start_value, etc...

What am I missing here? Am I passing the wrong information to currval?  Why does it say the 'column does not exist?'

Comment: The documentation uses single quotes, `''` instead of `""`.  do you still see the same error with both quote styles?

Comment: it also mentions that the case of the sequence is normalized to lowercase unless it contains double quotes, so you should probably have `currval('"Concept_cid_seq"')`...

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Yes, I've tried it both ways.  If I use single quotes it doesn't preserve the capitalization, so the error becomes `ERROR:  relation "concept_cid_seq" does not exist` instead.  I wonder if there is some significance to the fact that it calls it a relation instead of a column in that case...

Comment: @TokenMacGuy In response to your second comment, that was it.  Feel free to add an answer and I can mark it, or I will if you don't want the rep!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out that this was an issue with capitalization and quotes.  Because I wanted to preserve the capitalization of the relation name I needed to use *both* single *and* double quotes in order to pass the correct relation name to `currval`.

I changed the query to `SELECT currval('"Concept_cid_seq"');` (note the outer single quotes) and it worked correctly.